# How can I have a slideshow with matplotlib graphs in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to utilize a tkinter window with integrated matplotlib graphs that cycle every x seconds. However, this is what I have and I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [[3, 6, 1, 9, 2], [2, 0, 1, 4, 6], [6, 3, 8, 2, 0]]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
i = 0
while i < len(y):
    plt.plot(x, y[i])
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.clf()
    i += 1
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks like a job for `tkinter.after()`! [see here!](https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-after-method/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `after()`. You'll likely have an easier time if you wrap everything up in a simple Root `class`, so I've done that here.

```
# imports go here as usual...


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # init tk.Tk()
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.y = [[3, 6, 1, 9, 2], [2, 0, 1, 4, 6], [6, 3, 8, 2, 0]]
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        # set up the canvas
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        # begin cycling plots, starting with index 0
        self.index = 0
        self.cycle_plots(self.index) 

    def cycle_plots(self, index):
        plt.clf  # clear plot here
        self.index += 1  # go to the next index
        if self.index >= len(self.y):
            self.index = 0  # wrap around
        plt.plot(self.x, self.y[self.index])
        self.canvas.draw()  # update the canvas
       
        # after 1000mS, call this function again
        self.after(1000, lambda i=self.index: self.cycle_plots(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':  # run the app!
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Using a class makes it easier to pass your UI objects - like the Canvas - around between functions (methods). Here, `self` refers to your `Root` class, so anything inside it can share variables with `self.<varname>`, like `self.canvas`